# Jquery Accordion Format Issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

Has anyone come across this issue when using jquery accordions? When the top panel is active, the panel below displays large and covers the content from the active panel. **Important to note that this doesn't happen with any other panels** *see next image*

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles across this in the future...

The issue was that the project was missing some files. Upgraded project to jQuery 1.13.2 fixed the issue.